# How to create Geofence

Tags: android-ibeacon

In the qualcomm Gimbal manager, I am trying to "Create a New Geofence" when I enter the name and search address it is showing "Valid radial or polygonal geofence is required" error. Can anybody tell me how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Add Geofence" button in the top right corner then click the "Create Geofence" then you will see a popup with Name, Type, Raidus and address options. 
Name - can be anything as per your requirement
Type - based on your requirement you can use radial or polygon
      radial - will create a circular geofence
      polygon - will give you an option to create what ever shape you want.
Address - you can enter any google address available from then on you can drag and create where ever you want the geofence to be[image: circular geofence]
[image: ploygon geofence] and then finally hit create button in  the top right corner. You are done :)